# Microservice with Kong Gateway return 404

Tags: microservices, kong

I have Ubuntu System where docker is running with kong, konga and 1 microservice refdata-svc
**Service Config from Kong**

```
{"retries":5,"created_at":1700806774,"updated_at":1700883504,"enabled":true,"port":9005,"name":"refdata-svc","client_certificate":null,"id":"3e8a1e03-6eb0-48ba-8495-e7e525485eb0","tls_verify":null,"connect_timeout":60000,"tls_verify_depth":null,"tags":null,"ca_certificates":null,"host":"host.docker.internal","read_timeout":60000,"write_timeout":60000,"path":"/","protocol":"http"}
```

**Route Config from Kong**

```
{"preserve_host":false,"created_at":1700826574,"updated_at":1700890163,"service":{"id":"3e8a1e03-6eb0-48ba-8495-e7e525485eb0"},"paths":["/api/v1/refdata-svc"],"strip_path":true,"name":"refdata-svc","id":"5511545e-b7ed-4cb8-a768-6de216a35199","path_handling":"v1","request_buffering":true,"response_buffering":true,"methods":null,"sources":null,"destinations":null,"https_redirect_status_code":426,"tags":null,"snis":null,"protocols":["http","https"],"hosts":null,"headers":null,"regex_priority":0}
```

**Microservice Response**

```
http://localhost:9005/: {"message":"Welcome to ref-data!"}
```

**Kong Response**

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/refdata-svc : {"message":"Not found"}
```

What I am doing wrong ? Apreciate help

Answer (score 1):

Kong listens to proxy service on port 8000 (HTTP) and 8443 (HTTPS) by default.
You're hitting the admin API on port 8001 which has no endpoint at `/api/v1/refdata-svc`.